# 2 Factor Authentication Code Temporary Storage

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twilio

Using MVC and Twilio for SMS, when my user successfully enters their username and password, I generate a number to send to their phone and redirect them to a screen with a textbox for entering that code... my question, is where should I temporarily store that code so that I can compare it with what they enter?

ViewBag?
Database?
Session?

Comment: I'd go with Session (or Database if you wished for), definitely not ViewBag as i doubt you can retrieve it when you want to verify user's input for the 2FA.

Comment: ViewBag will be available in the screen I redirect to.  If they hit refresh, won't it get set to null?  If so, Session would be better even though I won't need the code stored anywhere after they successfully confirm it.

Comment: just give it a shot when in doubt. the best approach i could think of is going with Session. now off to try before downvoters swarm this question.

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here - you can check out our API for Authy, which does the token management and checking for you! https://www.twilio.com/docs/authy/api/one-time-passwords#send-a-one-time-password-via-sms

Comment: Thanks... I will look into both suggestions.